# How to remove extra text from a string in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, string

I have below string

```
string(47) "src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/marR48481a""
```

I want to get the youtube URL only from the above string i.e `https://www.youtube.com/embed/marR48481a` only!

I tried the below but it's not working

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $yturl);
$string = str_replace("",'src="', $string);


var_dump($string);
```

but this still prints the below string!

> string(47) "src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/mBqpaAKtnXE""

Comment: Where is the string coming from? It's possible there's a better way to do this.

Comment: @ChrisWhite from DB the whole string is an iframe. But I have only the above mentioned string in this variable `$yturl`

Comment: If it's always this exact string, why not simply use [`substr($string, 5, -2)`](https://eval.in/1104790)?

Comment: You can capture the url in group1 using this regex `.*(http[^"]+).*` and replace the whole string with `$1` to just get the URL. [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AKLR4X/1)

Comment: Use a mere `$string = str_replace(['src="', '"'], '', $string);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the needle & haystack backwards. Try this:

```
$string = str_replace('src="', '', $string);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0):

If your initial string is an iframe, it is better to use the proper tool to extract information in HTML rather than use a bunch of regex:

```
$html = '<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com" frameborder="0"/>' ;

$doc = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
@$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$url = $xpath->query('//iframe/@src')->item(0)->textContent;

echo $url ; // http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com
```